Does NextJS Do Garbage Collection from Storage for fetch Requests?
I am in the middle of switching from ReactNative to NextJS, and I like the fetch caching but Iam trying to figure out if NextJS does any "garbage collection" for invalidatedTags or does it just leave them on disk?
If it just leave them sitting there, can anyone recommend a method to delete invalidated objects?

Next.js does not automatically perform "garbage collection" for invalidated cache tags. Once a tag is invalidated, the cache remains until it is overwritten or manually cleared. To remove invalidated cache entries, you can periodically clear the cache using revalidatePath or similar methods, or implement a custom cache management strategy to delete stale objects.
